# Download URL document to a Folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to download several documents, to achieve this, I must build an URL programatically.
this is an example of the url: https://dwdemos.digitalsolutions.com.ec/DocuWare/Platform/WebClient/Client/FileDownload?did=4&rl=1c83caaa-dcd0-4fd5-91c9-f85ec4d869ae&queryInInvariantCulture=False

but when I try to download, I'm not getting the file, It seems I'm getting html content.

an example:

```
var docurl = "https://dwdemos.digitalsolutions.com.ec/DocuWare/Platform/WebClient/Client/FileDownload?did=4&rl=1c83caaa-dcd0-4fd5-91c9-f85ec4d869ae&queryInInvariantCulture=False";
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadFile( docurl, docsPath + "file.pdf" );
```

docsPath is a directory. This gives me an error.

But if i try:

```
webClient.DownloadFile( "http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf", docsPath + "file.pdf" );
```

Works fine. I know is not the same scenario than the first.

Please, Any Advice?

Comment: What is the error you receive?

Comment: It's because the file at `"dwdemos.digitalsolutions.com.ec"` is protected by authentication while the one at `"www.africau.edu"` is not.

Comment: _when I try to download, I'm not getting the file, It seems I'm getting html content._ - the link you provide redirects to a login page, but your code doesn't add any authentication. Is the login page perhaps the HTML you're seeing?

Comment: Thanks ,.. you’re right... I didn’t notice because I was already logged. I need encoding the credentials to that system, this according with our customer.,,. Thanks everybody.., if I have problems with Credentials included I’ll let you know.